# Salesforce Notes to be displayed under a single "Tab"

Tags: tab, notes

I have got a scenario where it is asked to display all the notes being entered for a "Lead, Account and Contact" to be shown under a single "Custom Tab". This tab shows the notes from these 3 objects with fields like for which "Lead/Account/Contact" that note is associated and who has entered it. There could also be notes coming from external application (as400 in this instance) via web services.

And this tab should be made available for few members of the Org.

Could anyone let me know if this scenario is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with Visualforce Tab.

You can query the note object in the Apex controller like such:

```
SELECT CreatedById,Id,OwnerId,ParentId FROM Note
```

You may need to build some logic to find out the type of parent etc, but I don't really see a technical limitation.

To include data from external applications, you can use http requests from the apex controller. It's up to you whether you'd like to display these separately or combine the data in a custom apex wrapper object of some sort.

Comment: Fine, is there a way to restrict this "Custom Tab" to only few members in the organization.

Comment: Yes.. you can configure acces to visualforce tabs the same as you can do for any other tab by profile or you could put it in a separate App.

Comment: Can your previous comment can be used for the notes coming from external application via web services?

Comment: Your question makes no mention of any system integration. You can do http call outs from the apex controller and display results on the page. But, if you have more details they could be updated into the question or you could ask more questions to dig  through specific problems once you start developing.

Comment: Well, I have updated the question now. **There could also be notes coming from external application (as400 in this instance) via web services.**